# Chrome extension: Send message from web page to chrome extension using background and content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to pass message from web Page to content script to background page. did the following code which in not working. 
When I click on clickme button -> send message to chrome extension

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "Fixes",
  "version": "2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "SomeFixes",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "storage"],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
   "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
    "js": ["contentscript.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }],
  "background":{
      "scripts":["background.js"]
  }
}
```

**page.html.**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
    var go = function() {
        var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent('hello');
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:go();">Click me</a>
</body>
</html><html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
    var go = function() {
        var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent('hello');
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:go();">Click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**contentscript.js**

```
document.addEventListener("hello", function(data) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("test");
})
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert("message received");
});
```

Idea is basically receive data from webpage to extension.

Comment: It works here. And as far as I can see you're doing it correctly. However if you test `page.html` locally as `file:///path/page.html` you need to use `<all_urls>` instead of `http://*/*` in manifest.json AND allow file access for your extension on chrome://extensions page.

Comment: Yes  wOxxOm, testing with local page, mean to say ,like this                 "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>","http://*/*","https://*/*"],
    "js": ["contentscript.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"  @wOxxOm,

Comment: So the problem's gone?

Comment: yes ,Thanks @wOxxOm, added to extension to chrome extensions, loaded the page.html local file, tried clicking 'clickme'. worked first time , but later I didn't see the alert. :( . how to give "allow file access"???

Comment: Go to `chrome://extensions` and click the checkbox: https://puu.sh/kTnae/06169245ea.png